# Counting question marks in each column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have question marks in my data frame as missing values that are denoted by "?". I want to write a code similar to:

```
sapply(X = df, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

that gives me the count of question marks in each column of my dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `colSums` on a logical matrix

```
colSums(df == "?", na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(x == "?", na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. == "?", na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

While reading the datasets, it may be better to replace with NA using `na.strings`

```
df <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = c("?", "NA", "N/A"))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will remember to use these for future variables.